# How does a for cycle loops trough items, if you delete and add one item mid-loop?

Tags: vba, loops, ms-word

I've wondered about this, on word 2007 this didn't work as I expected, and on word 2016 it did. Let-me explain:

I have a for loop

```
For i = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1).Shapes.count To 1 Step -1

 if  ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1).Shapes(i) matches condition, then

ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1).Shapes(i).delete
set newshape = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1).Shapes.Addpicture(new picture, bla, bla, bla..)

end if
next i
```

In this circumstance, will the loop encounter the newly added shape, and cycle trough it? Or will it ignore it?

To manage this issue I tough of setting ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1).Shapes(i) as an object, and delete it inside the loop, after inserting the new one.

- But what if I just set the one I want to delete invisible instead? Will the one inserted, be processed in the loop?

I also considered making a collection of all the shapes I wanted to delete, and then loop inside the collection to delete and add new shapes, in order to make sure he wouldn't loop trough a shape inserted in the middle of it.

Thanks for any insights on this question

Comment: Why not try it out yourself? Then ask a question if you run into a problem you're trying to solve...

Comment: I tried, and I got different results in word 2007 and word 2016.

Comment: The reverse loop will not encounter newly added shapes, however if you go in forward loop (since the newly added shapes will acquire highest orders of index) some of the highest order new shapes may be encountered in the loop. Experimented in 2007 and found working OK (in reverse loop only). In forward loop some newly added shapes gets replaced leaving old shapes untouched. Since reverse loop is working working correctly, there seems no need to make it invisible. You may try it your self (may be without condition) as commented by Cindy Meister.

Comment: Pl check if you worked in a forward loop in 2007.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Cindy said, your code would be more efficient and easier to follow as:

```
With ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1)
  For i = .Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    If .Shapes(i) matches condition Then
      .Shapes(i).Delete
      Set newshape = .Shapes.AddPicture(new picture, bla, bla, bla)
    End If
  Next i
End With
```

Comment: Setting a "With" has nothing to do with the question. The code is working with word 2016, but I'm not sure if I'm being lucky with the pictures that are being replaced, since in word 2007 it skips some of them. Also, doesn't answer regarding just setting the invisibility.

Comment: As I said at the outset: *In addition to what Cindy said*…